# Php preg_match ul li errors

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

To get the li values in this code;
    I m use to curl with php. After Html has too many ul. So I have to put selector class name.

```
 <ul class="pagination ng-scope">
    <li class="arrow previous unavailable"><a href="#listable"><i></i></a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="http://blablaa.com/1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://blablaa.com/2">2</a></li>
    <li class="arrow next"><a href="http://blablaa/2#listable" class="next"><i></i></a></li>
</ul>


preg_match('#<ul class="pagination">(.*?)</ul>#msi', $result['result'], $pagination);
print_r($pagination);
preg_match_all('#<li>.*?</li>#msi', $pagination[1], $pages);

for ($i = 1; $i <= count($pages[0]) + 1; $i++) {
    $link = $baselink . "/" . $i;
}

echo $link;
```

but not result.Please help me, thanks.

Comment: What values you are expecting ?

Comment: @RavinderReddy   I want to page count. Like 1 and 2

Comment: Are you trying to read that HTML using PHP as if it was JavaScript/jQuery?! That ain't gonna work : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: @RavinderReddy I use curl with php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You start you regular expression with

```
<ul class="pagination">
```

and your HTML starts with

```
<ul class="pagination ng-scope">
```

which is clearly not a match for the expression. Change `<ul class="pagination">` to `<ul class="pagination.*">` to start getting matches.

---

If you want the page numbers, you can use `'#<a[^>]*>(\d+)</a>#msi'` regex, which collects all the numbers within an `<a>` tag. [example](https://ideone.com/FFAhvt)

Comment: preg_match('#<ul class="pagination.">(.*?)</ul>#msi', $result['result'], $pagination);          This also gives an error

Comment: You can try this: `preg_match_all('#<a[^>]*>(\d+)</a>#msi', $result['result'], $pagination);`
This will give you all number that is located within an <a> tag.

Comment: Thanks its work but I forgot to say,   I m use to curl with php. After Html has too many ul. So I have to put selector class name. How can we do @Laposhasu

Comment: Your original idea is good. First find the ul tag, then find the page numbers in it

Comment: Be aware that your original code find ul-tags with `pagination` class but in your html there is `pagination ng-scope`.